# Meteor jQuery plugins initialization by onRendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Why does this jQuery plugin initialization code not work unless I wrap it with `setTimeout`?

When I use `setTimeOut`, everything is fine.
Can you help me?

This doesn't work:

```
Template.checker_one_item_time.onRendered(function(){

    $('#time_custom_scroll').mCustomScrollbar({
        setHeight: 244,
        mouseWheel:{
            enable: true,
            axis: "y"
        }
    });
});
```

This works:

```
Template.checker_one_item_time.onRendered(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#time_custom_scroll').mCustomScrollbar({
            setHeight: 244,
            mouseWheel:{
                enable: true,
                axis: "y"
            }
        });
    }, 2000)    
});
```

Comment: What error is happening?

Comment: You may be rendering the template before subscriptions are ready, and so some of your markup does not exist (not until template rerenders when subscription is ready)

Comment: Error is wrong initialization plugin - without content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you rendering your template without waiting for any subscriptions it depends on to be ready?  You may want to [look at this pattern](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe)

> Another example where you want to initialize a plugin when the subscription is done:

```
Template.listing.onRendered(function () {
  var template = this;

  template.subscribe('listOfThings', function () {
    // Wait for the data to load using the callback
    Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
      // Use Tracker.afterFlush to wait for the UI to re-render
      // then use highlight.js to highlight a code snippet
      highlightBlock(template.find('.code'));
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Yea! With subscribe it works - perfect. I see than plugin works.

Comment: You could look into waiting for the subscriptions in iron:router, as shown here - http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#wait-and-ready.  However now that flow router is becoming more popular, and MDG is indicating that they favour the more minimal approach of flow router, I'd advise keeping your subscriptions, etc, out of the router, and attached to the template instead.